# why __init__ has to be extended and appended?

Tags: python

I met this line of code from an `__init__.py` file. Can anyone explain to me what the last two lines mean? I understand that `__all__` is an empty list at the start. In particular have a hard time understanding the arguments `apps.__all__` and `'apps'`, and why there is a need to extend when there is already append, or vice versa.

```
__all__ = []

from . import apps
from .apps import *
__all__.extend(apps.__all__)
__all__.append('apps')
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be done this way. The code dynamically collects the apps modules and appends them to its own magic variable `__all__` to export them. With this trick you don't have to update `init.py` when you add a new module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: It doesn't, it's just for convenience when the package is too large or when you want to allow a star-import for a user.

It extends the default allowed symbols (`[]` for you, see `__all__` value) for the [star import (`from x import *`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44834/5994041) so it contains all of the pre-defined symbols from `apps.__all__` and also `apps` itself as well.

That means if your module is called `hello` and I do this:

```
# apps.py
__all__ = [x, y, z]

# __init__.py
__all__ = []
from . import apps
from .apps import *
__all__.extend(apps.__all__)
__all__.append('apps')

# main.py
from hello import *
# imports __init__ and executes unguarded lines
# __all__ in __init__.py is initialized
# apps.py is imported
#   apps.py code is executed
#   __all__ for apps.py is assembled
# star-import from apps.py imports all allowed symbols from apps.py
# __all__ is extended with "apps" and apps.__all__
# then your star-import in main.py would expose all of the listed symbols
```

I'll have these symbols available as "variables" in the module I issue the import in:

```
x
y
z
apps
```

i.e. I can then reference in my `main.py`: `x`, `y`, `z` contained in the `apps.py` module directly or I can reference them through the `apps` value (`main.apps` after star import) like this: `apps.x`, `apps.y`, `apps.z`.

If you do not specify the `__all__` you can import everything as the `__all__` variable serves only as a guard and this way of using it in the `__init__.py` of a package ensures you can star-import just by package's name and have all of the necessary functions, constants, etc present without knowing the package's structure. However it can be also problematic with circular imports.

Comment: thanks @Peter Badida! your explanation is very clear. :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package):

> The import statement uses the following convention: if a package’s
> `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when `from package import *` is encountered.

In last two lines, you are filling the `__all__`.

Because `apps.__all__` is also a list and you want the items inside that list to be appended we use `.extend()`, otherwise the list itself appends to `__all__`.

Next we include the name of the submodule(or package if it has `__init__.py`) that is going to be imported which is `apps`. (Remember we imported `apps` module/package in line 3), so it's in global namespace now.

By doing those 2 lines, when you import the current package, You have not only items of the `apps.__all__` but also `apps` module/package itself availabe in namespace of wherever the import statement is.

Comment: thanks! that makes sense, and I understand that `apps.__all__` means that the apps directory contains the `__init__.py` file? And what does `.apps` mean? Could I write something like from . import apps
from .apps import *

Comment: @kwaldner Normally a package defines `__all__` in it's `__init__.py` to handle what it wants to export. Also modules can have `__all__`. Whenever you see dot before the name of the packages in import statement you're using "relative imports" and single dot means current package, `..` means the parent package.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. :)